# Dropbox does not sync after suspend

Tags: suspend, dropbox

Whenever I suspend my Ubuntu, and then rewake it, Dropbox does not sync, so I don't see files that I edited on other computers. How can I make it sync?

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to right-click on the Dropbox icon and check if your Syncing is enabled?
You also can find more in the preferences of Dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround would be to Pause syncing, then Resume it using Dropbox icon's context menu. This will lead to re-indexing the whole Dropbox directory though, so you'll have to wait for it to finish before it starts actual synchronization.